# How to display detail fragments side by side in tablet and vertical stack in mobile?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to add multiple dynamic fragments in dual panel? I need to add Dual panel for Tablet and single pane for mobile. Also in Detail part having two fragments, if tablet it shows fragments side by side,else if mobile it shows fragments top and below.How to do this. 
can i add another framelayout in dual panel? or In detail fragment,simply add linear layout?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to android.com. There is quite a good tutorial how to support different layouts for tablets and smartphones. Basically you create to different layout folders (one for tablet, one for phone) and create the layout you want in them. Android will automatically select the right one.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html